# Dynamically set property of View in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
App.Views.WidgetAvailable = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',

        className: 'widget',

        template: template('available_template'),

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
```

So I got this view which is used by two collections, the problem is that only the template property is different in the two cases. Thus I am trying to figure out how to set the *template:* property dynamically.

Does any one have a clue how to do this?

Greetz,

Comment: Try passing it in as a parameter when you [initialize](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) your view.

Answer (score 3):

Should be as easy as this:

```
 initialize: function(){
                this.template = options.template;
                return this;
            }
```

Then when you call it:

```
var view = new App.Views.WidgetAvailable( { template : '...' } );
```

Thanks to [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) for correction

Comment: An options object might be better (`new V({ template: '...' })` and `this.template = options.template` in `initialize`) as that preserves the standard constructor interface.

Comment: After all the idea of this answer is ok, but it does not work, the thing described in the comment did the job after all

Answer (score 1):

You are able to pass in parameters into your [initialize](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) method, so you should be able to just pass in the template.

For example:

```
App.Views.WidgetAvailable = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function (template) {
           this.template = template(template);

    }
      //the rest of your views code
});

var view1 = new App.Views.WidgetAvailable(template1);
var view2 = new App.Views.WidgetAvailable(template2);
```